# Cannot read from read-replica in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I set the variables in sql:

```
SET default_transaction_read_only = TRUE
SET yb_read_from_followers=true;
SET yb_follower_read_staleness_ms=30000;
```

But yet my read query ran on master nodes instead. A screenshot:

[image]

The behavior does not seem consistent though. On some queries the read directly from the table seems to be happening on the read node (verified by looking at iostats on the nodes) ... but some queries that use an index seem to go to the main cluster. I’m using yugabyte-2.8.1.0-b37

Answer (score 0):

That version doesn’t support reading from replicas when an index is being used. A fix has been included in https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/commit/2ba51212d874bb3e68a676b59f7f69635223892c and will be included in the next minor release 2.8.2.